# Enabling scrollbar on y-axis of the highcharts heat map does not work

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heat map for a large data set with scroll bar enabled on y-axis. Enabling scrollbar on y axis and setting min and max brings up the scroll bar but it is disabled and not scrollable. But doing the same for x axis works correctly.

Here is the sample graph with data.
https://jsfiddle.net/srikrishnamoorthi/7ugxwb69/1/

```
yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}:00'
        },
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24],
        tickWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 12,
        reversed: true,
        scrollbar: {
          enabled: true
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug related to the boost module and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12889

As a workaround, add this simple plugin:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'hasExtremes', function() {
        return false;
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5xcqeupj/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts